# Template repository with submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I've been setting up a template repository with a submodule to another repo that has our common lib.

```
./common @ 6805991 (on branch "foo")
./src
.gitmodules
Dockerfile
dockerize
```

Is there a way to make it so that when the repo is used as a template on github, `common` points to the latest commit on the branch "foo"?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [dependabot](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/dependabot/dependabot-version-updates/configuration-options-for-the-dependabot.yml-file#package-ecosystem) to update Git submodules. It'll open pull requests to the latest commit on the branch configured in `.gitmodules`.

Comment: How would I set this up?

Comment: You have to add a dependabot config file at `.github/dependabot.yml` in the repository; see [this example](https://github.com/bewuethr/dotfiles/blob/main/.github/dependabot.yml).